# Dimension of Overring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an (Noetherian) integral domain (of dimension one), $K$ its quotient field, $B$ a subring of $K$ such that $A\subseteq B \subseteq K$. Can we determine the dimension of $B$ in general? what about if we require $B$ is a valuation ring? Is there some reference about this?

Maybe this is too vague, I am  more concerning the following case: When
$A$ is local Noetherian, and $B$ is a valuation ring which dominates $A$, and $B$ is a subring of $K$, can we determine the dimension of $B$ in this setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the **Krull-Akizuki Theorem** that $B$ is Noetherian of dimension at most one.  Thus it has dimension one iff it is not a field.  See for instance Matusmura's *Commutative ring theory* for a full statement and proof.